# MassTransit Change Exchange Type Problems

Tags: .net, .net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

I want to change exchange-type in Masstransit.My sample code block is below.

```
_bus = BusConfigurator.Instance.ConfigureBus(_massTransitSettings,
          (cfg, host) =>
          {
              cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("example-queue",
                  e =>
                  {
                      e.AutoDelete = true;
                      e.Durable = true;
                      e.ExchangeType = ExchangeType.Direct;
                      e.Consumer(() =>
                      {
                          //consume operation
                      });
                  });
          });
```

When I do my tests, I still see the exchange-type value in rabbitmq fanout. Where am I making mistakes ?

Thank you for your support..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There is a sample](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-Direct) that shows how to set up direct exchange routing using RabbitMQ and MassTransit.

The configuration of exchange properties is also [documented](https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/topology/rabbitmq.html).